# Run two php application in two different ports in apache

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

i have two sample application in the same machine.
it is PHP.
i am in need to develope application that supports cross domain cookies.
so ,now i am trying to run two application in different port in apache server. so for that i changed the port number in httpd.conf.
like i added 
**Listen 8080**
and i am not getting about the

```
VirtualHost *:80  
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com  
 DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com      
ServerName dummy-host.example.com   
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log  
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
```

Please let me know how to add that for my second port 8080.
i run my application from the browser as xxx.xx.x.xx/First/Cookies.
i tried as xxx.xx.x.xx:80/First/Cookies.----this is fine,
how can i try it for 8080 for my second application.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

This should be the bare minimum you need. Add other useful directives at will.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/x/z/
        ... the usual stuff ...
</VirtualHost>

Listen 20117
<VirtualHost *:20117>
        DocumentRoot /home/x/y/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost SERVERNAME:8080>
ServerAdmin webmaster@another-host.example.com
ServerName SERVERNAME:8080
DocumentRoot "/www/docs/another-host.example.com"
ErrorLog logs/another-host.example.com-error_log  
CustomLog logs/another-host.example.com-access_log common
```

also add this line in httpd.conf file

`Listen 8080`

```
<Directory "/www/docs/another-host">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

also add this

Comment: thnks for ur reply..
i am new to this.. so don't find fault if i am silly....
all i need is explanation of what this contains and where all do i ned to edit to make my application work in port 8080 also.
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com  
 DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com      
ServerName dummy-host.example.com   
ErrorLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log  
CustomLog logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common

Comment: Please kindly help in doing this as i am struck up with this.

Comment: I have added the Listen:8080 and  <VirtualHost SERVERNAME:8080> ServerName SERVERNAME:8080 </virtualHost>.  Thanks for ur reply. i got ur answer by the consequent read.